# find elasticsearch service endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I'm on my trial to test elasticcloud. But now I got problem to create pipeline from logstash to elasticcloud. Here is my logstash.conf output

```
output {
        stdout{codec=>rubydebug}
        elasticsearch
        {
            hosts=>["https://<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"]
 index=>"testindex"
user=>elasticdeploymentcredentials
password=>elasticdeploymentcredentials
 }
}
```

But it always returning error as:

```
[WARN ] 2021-03-29 12:24:50.148 [Ruby-0-Thread-9: :1] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] <clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io"}
[WARN ] 2021-03-29 12:24:55.158 [Ruby-0-Thread-9: :1] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] <clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io: Name or service not known"}
[WARN ] 2021-03-29 12:25:00.163 [Ruby-0-Thread-9: :1] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] <clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io"}
[WARN ] 2021-03-29 12:25:05.170 [Ruby-0-Thread-9: :1] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] <clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io: Name or service not known"}
[WARN ] 2021-03-29 12:25:10.175 [Ruby-0-Thread-9: :1] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] <clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io"}
```

It is possible for me to curl it with my credential as :
`[root@localhost testconfig]# curl https://elasticdeploymentcredentials:elasticdeploymentcredentials@<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:9243`
it returning

```
  "name" : "name",
  "cluster_name" : "<clusterid>",
  "cluster_uuid" : "<clusteruuid>",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.12.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "build_hash",
    "build_date" : "2021-03-18T06:17:15.410153305Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to connect to Elastic Cloud via the username/password from the deployment, try to use the Cloud_ID/Cloud_Auth combination:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://<clusterid>.asia-southeast1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    cloud_id => "your cloudid from the console"
    cloud_auth => "elastic:password"
  }
}
```

The `cloud_auth` parameter is where you are actually going to use the username/password from the deployment. More information here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.12/connecting-to-cloud.html